# telnetのパスワードの入力の自動化について

Tags: bash, expect

自動でtelnetで接続するための下記のスクリプトにおいて
パスワードの自動入力に失敗する理由を知りたく存じます。

手動で「"magic" + リターンキー」でログインできているのですが、
スクリプト上で send "magic\r"と記載しているのに、 Incorrect passwordになるのは
なぜでしょうか。

telnet.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set address "192.168.10.1"
set port "23"
spawn telnet $address $port

expect "ready" { sleep 5; send "\r"; }
expect "Password" { sleep 5; send "magic\r"; }
expect "$" { sleep 5; send "pof1\r"; }
expect "$" { sleep 5; send "exit\r"; }
expect eof
```

期待する結果（手動で、パスワードを「magic」と入力）

```
spawn telnet 192.168.10.1 23
Trying 192.168.10.1... 
Connected to 192.168.10.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 (Noname) server ready.

Password:
OK
Noname> pof1 220 192.168.10.1 Command OK.
Noname> exit 221 Goodbye.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

実行結果

```
$ ./PWON1.sh
Trying 192.168.10.1...
Connected to 192.168.10.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220  (Noname) server ready.
Password:
Incorrect password
Incorrect password
```

\rを\nに変えたところ

```
hoge$ sudo ./telnet.sh
spawn telnet 192.168.10.1 23
Trying 192.168.10.1...
Connected to 192.168.10.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 A (Noname) server ready.
hoge$
```

ここで終わりました。

Comment: `\r` を `\n` にするとどうなりますか？

Comment: hoge$ sudo ./telnet.sh
spawn telnet 192.168.10.1 23
Trying 192.168.10.1...
Connected to 192.168.10.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
 220 A (Noname) server ready.
hogei$

ここで終わりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect`で期待する文字がログイン時に出ていないと思います。
これで動きませんか？

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set address "192.168.10.1"
set port "23"
spawn telnet $address $port

expect "ready" {
    sleep 5
    send "\r"
}
expect "Password" {
    sleep 5
    send "magic\r"
}
expect "OK" {
    send "sleep 5\r"
    send "pof1\r"
    send "sleep 5\r"
    send "exit\r"
}
expect eof
```

それとファイルの改行コードは`LF(\n)`だけになっていますか？
`CRLF(\r\n)`ではLinux上で実行できません。

Comment: 元質問のexpect "$"は、$文字が正規表現の入力終端と解釈されちゃってるって可能性はないですかね。

Comment: @shirok 正規表現として認識させるには`expect -re`にしないといけないと思います。なので質問者さんのコードだとログイン先がbashでない場合は動作が止まってしまいますね。

Comment: expect の send コマンドにおけるリターンコードは \r ではありませんか？（マニュアルにも「文字は直ちに送られる。ただし、入力にラインバッファのあるプログラムでは、 リターンコードが送られるまで文字が読まれない。リターンコードは、 "\r"と表記する。」と記載があります）また、Escape character is '^]'. は、telnet コマンドの出力（コマンドモードに移行するためのエスケープ文字を教えてくれている）なので、expect のスクリプトとは関係ないように思います。

Comment: @pandax381 確かに`man`では`\r`となっていますね･･･修正しておきます。`Escape character is '^]'.`に関しては`telnet`コマンドの出力でしたか。こちらではセキュリティの関係上`slogin`でしか動作確認しておらず、失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

1. "ready"に対して"\r"は必要ですか？　必要なければ、これもパスワードとして送られてしまうため、ログインできないのかなと思いました。
2. Ubuntu 14.04でtelnetログイン環境を作って擬似的にテストしたところ、「expect "$"」はうまく動かず、「expect $」か「expect "$ "」（$の後ろにスペース）か「expect "\\$"」とすると動作しました。
3. 上記テスト環境では、パスワードの末尾などは「\r」も「\n」でもどちらでも動作しました。（ネットで検索してみると、どっちのパターンも出てきますが「\n」の方が多いようです。）